# Setting application badge using provisional authorization in iOS 12

Tags: push-notification, ios12

So iOS 12 introduced Provisional Authorization for Quiet Notifications that could be seen in Notification Center but not on the Lock screen. It has very cool advantage - you don't need user's approval to send one.

Several articles ([smashingmagazine.com](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/09/preparing-your-app-for-ios-12-notifications/), [gadgethacks.com](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/news/100-coolest-new-ios-12-features-you-didnt-know-about-0182804/), etc.) claim that iOS app will be able to set it's badge if received Provisional Authorization.

Is it really possible to set app badge when app is Provisionally Authorized?

I request authorization using code below:

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
     requestAuthorizationWithOptions:UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionProvisional
     completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *_Nullable error) {
       if (granted) {
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
       }
     }];
```

I receive token at `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` that could be used to send Push Notification. When I send Push Notification with a payload `{"aps":{"alert":"Testing..","badge":1}}` I see it in Notification Center but app doesn't get badged.

I tried setting badge using `UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;` but it didn't work as well. It works though if I request regular authorization without providing UNAuthorizationOptionProvisional option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here.

It seems, that app badges are off by default for provisional authorization. I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

But you can see it in the apps notification settings. The "Badges" switch is off by default:

[image: Notification Settings]

Answer (score 1):

App badges are also off for provisional notifications in iOS 15.

So this doesn't do anything, unless you go to System Settings and toggle the badges switch.

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .provisional]) { granted, error in
  if granted {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = Int.random(in: 1...1000)
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone know a workaround?